# JavaScript form validation returns Uncaught TypeError regarding value property

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project website with a registration form in which I want to check if the password is ok, if the email is ok, and etc.
I get no output at all (No alerts) and the page just refreshes itself, when checking the console I see an error that's described at the end.

That's the function:

```js
function validationCheck() {
  var name = document.forms["register"]["fName"];
  var email = document.forms["register"]["email"];
  var phone = document.forms["register"]["phonenumber"];
  var password = document.forms["register"]["password"];

  if (name.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please enter your name.");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (email.value == "") {
    window.alert(
      "Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (phone.value == "") {
    window.alert(
      "Please enter your telephone number.");
    phone.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (password.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please enter your password");
    password.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="register" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="return validationCheck();">
  <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
  <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline"></i></div>
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" runat="server" id="username" /></div>
  <!-- Username #11 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" runat="server" id="email"></div>
  <!-- Email #1 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" runat="server" id="password"></div>
  <!-- Password #2 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" runat="server" id="fName" /></div>
  <!-- First Name #8 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" runat="server" id="lName" /></div>
  <!-- Last Name #9 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="date" name="birthdate" runat="server" id="birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" /></div>
  <!-- Birthdate #3 -->
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" title="Phone Number" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number" runat="server" id="phonenumber" /></div>
  <!-- Phone Number #4 -->
  <span></span>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="gender" name="gender" runat="server" class="form-control" style="color:#6c757d">
      <option value="Gender" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="camera" name="camera-brand" runat="server" class="form-control" style="color:#6c757d">
      <option value="Camera Brand" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Camera Brand</option>
      <option value="Nikon">Nikon</option>
      <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
      <option value="Fuji">Fuji</option>
      <option value="Sony">Sony</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lens" placeholder="Lens" runat="server" id="lens" /></div>
  <!-- Lens #10 -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="genre" name="genre" runat="server" class="form-control" style="color:#6c757d">
      <option value="Sport">Sports</option>
      <option value="Wildlife">Wildlife</option>
      <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option>
      <option value="Portrait">Portrait</option>
      <option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" runat="server" id="submit">Sign up</button></div>
</form>
```

The error I am receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use [recommended APIs](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)? It’s possible that you can submit the form before the DOM is fully loaded. Make sure the [DOM is loaded](/q/14028959/4642212) and see [How to prevent form from being submitted?](/q/3350247/4642212). Use `document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("submit", (event) => { event.preventDefault(); /* Perform validation. When ready to submit: */ event.target.submit(); });`. Do not use `onsubmit`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon How is it possible to run the function before the DOM is loaded, since it's run from the element's `onsubmit` attribute?

Comment: Which line is getting the error?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using the snippet.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Hey, In the code you gave me, I should write the name of the function "validationCheck();", or write the whole function content inside of this?

Comment: Also it seems like the error is gone in the snippet but it doesn't work for me, That's really strange.

Comment: @SebastianSimon If I understood correctly, that's what I did: `        document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            validationCheck();
            event.target.submit();
        });`

and I've received this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is possible! HTML is incorporated into the DOM as soon as the browser receives it, chunk by chunk. `onsubmit` is active as soon as the element is rendered, which happens as soon as the `>` of the opening tag is received. A slow enough server gives you enough time to submit the form while `document.readyState === "loading"`, and half the DOM is loaded. I’ve just confirmed that with a proof of concept Node server.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko That code is almost correct; you still need to use the return value of `validationCheck`. For example: `if(validationCheck()){ event.target.submit(); }`. And as I said, you need to make sure that the DOM is loaded before executing this. The linked post lists several approaches.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Maybe if you're using a 20 year old computer you might be able to click on the submit button before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Barmar The server needs to be slow, not the client. The server doesn’t need to be 20 years old to be slow to respond.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have managed to reproduce this worked:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', validationCheck);
    function validationCheck(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     const form = new FormData(ev.target);
     const name = form.get('fName'); //the name of the property from the form.
    
     if(name == '') {
     return window.alert(text);
    }
    
    ev.target.submit();
    }
</script>
```

The use of event.preventDefault() is to prevent the default action of submiting the form and the refreshing of the page, allowing you to do your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after hours and hours of testing I finally understood what was the problem. I've had a site built using ASP.NET, meaning that instead of head and body tags I've asp::... tags.

So after I've got rid of them and changed them to  and  everything worked as it should after I've put this script into the body and not into the head as required in the ASP.NET format.

The code is in fact working.